# Incrementing $_SESSION index in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $j=0;
?>
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="step-3.php" >
 <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
    <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
        <span>
            Add another Driver
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"> 
            </i>
        </span>
    </div>
 </div>
</form>

<script>
  $("#add_driver").click(function () {  
 $( "#add_driver_section").replaceWith( "<div class='wrap-input100 validate- 
 input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' data-validate = 'Enter Your First Name'> <span 
 class='label-input100'>Firstname *</span> <input class='input100' 
 type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Your First Name ' <?php 
 if(isset($_SESSION['name'][++$j])){echo "value='".$_SESSION['name'] 
 [$j]."'";}?> ></div>");});
</script>
```

`$_SESSION['name']` is an array with multiple values. I need to increment the value of `$j` so as to get a new index of `$_SESSION['name']` every time the `add_driver` is clicked. This code works only the first time. The rest of the time it prints the same value as that in the first time. I am unable to show you the rest of the code or screenshots of the output because of company rules. Please tell me what is wrong with my code and how to acheive what i'm looking for. I only want some method to increment the index. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use a hidden field to store the value of index.

Comment: @AmitJoki but then how will i use the value inside php script. can you please show a sample code?

Comment: rather than increment the in php, on click increment a java script variable and then assign it to a php variable. or else store the incremented value in a hidden field or use cookies with jquery. In this way it won't work.

Comment: @PatrickEvans already tried it. not working.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna but that too will only assign the value once to php.

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION is a server variable, so you can't change it on the client side without interacting with the server. I would recomend you to use AJAX.
When the button is clicked, an AJAX request loads an empty page that increases the $_SESSION variable. (also you have to store $j also as a session variable, so you can have a track of it)

so for example:

in some file called myFile.php, you increment the index and retrieve the name in that index.

```
<?php
//this file just increases j everytime is loaded
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['j'])){
    $_SESSION['j']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['j'] = 0;
}
$result['name'] = $_SESSION['name'][$_SESSION['j']];
die(json_encode($result));
```

then in you button:

```
$("#myButton").click(function (evento) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "myFile.php",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            alert("The name[j] is " + data.name)
            // do here what you did in your button before
            // DONT use PHP echos here, use the data.name variable to access the $_SESSION['name'][$j] value
        }
    });
});
```

*Remember* that PHP is a preprocesor, so when the page loads in the client side, everithing PHP printed is now a constant. so you cannot use the echoed values and make them change.

Comment: is there really no lesser complicated method??

Comment: How often does $_SESSION['name'] changes?

Comment: the value to `$_SESSION['name']` is added dynamically so we do not know the count.

Comment: You could send all the $_SESSION['name'] data drom the beginning, the problem is that if it changes after the user loaded the page, then he won't notice. If the user that loads the page is the same one that changes $_SESSION['name'], then (only then) it's a good option.

Answer (score 1):

There is another method, and that is to send all the $_SESSION['name'] variable and use it in the client side. the problem is that **if $_SESSION['name'] changes after the user loaded the page, then he won't notice.**
So it would be like this:
(not tested, please excuse syntax errors)

```
<script>
    var names = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['name']); ?>");
    var count = 0;
    $("#add_driver").click(function () {
        count++;
        alert("now the name you needed is here: " + names[count]) //you have the name in names[count], do what you will
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can i somehow use this code: `if(isset($_SESSION['name']))($j=sizeof($_SESSION['name']); echo "var j=".$j;)` in the php script and access  `$_SESSION` directly from javascript using `var j` as the index and incrementing or decrementing it as reqd.??

Comment: You can count it in the client side too. Instead of using `sizeof($_SESSION['name'])` you can use `names.length`. I would recommend you to make another question explaining what you want to do (instead of how) so maybe I can help you finding the best way to handle this problem, because I really don't think that this approach of mixing client and server side is the best.